# OCaml Compiler on Windows - compiling module error. (i686-w64-mingw32-as)

Tags: cygwin, mingw, ocaml

I'm using Windows 7 64x and in my next semester, I'll have OCaml as main language in one of my lectures and I am more of a "Windows" person (I have windows version and cygwin-based version). So I decided to go over [this tutorial](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html).

Now here's the problem:
I've created files `amodule.ml` and `bmodule.ml` as specified in the link. However, when I'm trying to execute following lines on the commandline:

```
ocamlopt -c amodule.ml
```

I get following error:

```
'i686-w64-mingw32-as' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
File "amodule.ml", line 1:
Error: Assembler error, input left in file C:\Users\Devate\AppData\Local\Temp\camlasm0d9121.s
```

And almost the same error comes with `bmodule.ml` and using the last line:

```
ocamlopt -o hello amodule.cmx bmodule.cmx
```

After doing that - I get two new files named `amodule.cmi` and `bmodule.cmi`.
However, if I try doing compiling using cygwin version, I get no errors (I get both `amodule.cmi` and `amodule.cmx` - same with bmodule).

However with last line in cygwin I get tons of errors:

```
ocamlopt -o hello amodule.cmx bmodule.cmx

/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/std_exit.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o)' is incompatible with
i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(i386.o)' is incompatible with
i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o)' is incompatible with
i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(str.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(minor_gc.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compare.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(sys.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(extern.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(memory.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(callback.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(startup.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(alloc.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(custom.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(roots.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(signals_asm.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(backtrace.o)' is incompatible
with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(printexc.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(signals.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(weak.o)' is incompatible with
i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(gc_ctrl.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(major_gc.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(misc.o)' is incompatible with
i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(finalise.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(md5.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(freelist.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(globroots.o)' is incompatible
with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(parsing.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(debugger.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compact.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__entry'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x5): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `camlPervasives__entry'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0xc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x1c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x2c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit__entry'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x35): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `camlStd_exit__entry'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x3c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_globals_inited'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x5e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x9e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0xee): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x12e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x16e): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x22e): undefined reference to `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x26e): undefined reference to `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x2a3): undefined reference to `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x2de): undefined reference to `caml_young_limit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `caml_call_gc'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x2b8): undefined reference to `camlPervasives'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x2d0): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x3d8): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__data_begin'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x3e0): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__data_end'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x408): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit__data_begin'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x410): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit__data_end'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x430): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__code_begin'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x438): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__code_end'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x460): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit__code_begin'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x468): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit__code_end'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x480): undefined reference to `caml_system__frametable'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x488): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__frametable'
/tmp/camlstartup942177.o:fake:(.data+0x4a0): undefined reference to `camlStd_exit__frametable'
bmodule.o:fake:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__print_endline_1257'
amodule.o:fake:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `camlPervasives__print_endline_1257'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_End_of_file'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.text+0x493): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Failure'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.text+0x4d3): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Invalid_argument'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.text+0xa76): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_End_of_file'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.text+0xb18): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x184): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x194): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x1bc): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x2b0): undefined reference to `_caml_curry4'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x2c0): undefined reference to `_caml_curry4'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x2d0): undefined reference to `_caml_curry4'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x2f8): undefined reference to `_caml_curry3'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x320): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x330): undefined reference to `_caml_curry4'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x340): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x374): undefined reference to `_caml_curry3'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x384): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x3dc): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x404): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x414): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x448): undefined reference to `_caml_curry2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x458): more undefined references to `_caml_curry2' follow
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x524): undefined reference to `_caml_curry3'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7c4): undefined reference to `_fmod'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7cc): undefined reference to `_floor'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7d0): undefined reference to `_ceil'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7d4): undefined reference to `_tanh'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7d8): undefined reference to `_tan'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7dc): undefined reference to `_sqrt'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7e0): undefined reference to `_sinh'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7e4): undefined reference to `_sin'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7ec): undefined reference to `_log10'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7f0): undefined reference to `_log'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7f4): undefined reference to `_cosh'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x7f8): undefined reference to `_cos'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x800): undefined reference to `_atan2'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x804): undefined reference to `_atan'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x808): undefined reference to `_asin'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x80c): undefined reference to `_acos'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x814): undefined reference to `_exp'
C:\OCaml\lib/stdlib.a(pervasives.o):fake:(.data+0x818): undefined reference to `_pow'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x3f9): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x429): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x457): undefined reference to `_atoi'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x86c): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0xa29): undefined reference to `___divdi3'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0xaa6): undefined reference to `___moddi3'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0xde3): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0xe56): undefined reference to `___udivdi3'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(ints.o):ints.c:(.text+0x131a): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(i386.o):fake:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `_caml_program'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(i386.o):fake:(.text+0x211): undefined reference to `_caml_apply2'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(i386.o):fake:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `_caml_apply3'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Failure'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Invalid_argument'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x23f): undefined reference to `_caml_bucket_Out_of_memory'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `_caml_bucket_Stack_overflow'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Sys_error'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_End_of_file'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x283): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Division_by_zero'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Not_found'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x2a1): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Sys_blocked_io'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Invalid_argument'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x326): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Match_failure'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Assert_failure'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(fail.o):fail.c:(.text+0x334): undefined reference to `_caml_exn_Undefined_recursive_module'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `_write'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `__lseeki64'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `_close'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `__lseeki64'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `__lseeki64'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x351): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x464): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x47b): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x4b4): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x554): undefined reference to `__lseeki64'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x5c8): undefined reference to `_read'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x5f8): undefined reference to `_read'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x71d): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x73a): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x786): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x882): undefined reference to `__lseeki64'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x90c): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0xafd): undefined reference to `_close'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x1284): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x12aa): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x1308): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(str.o):str.c:(.text+0x41d): undefined reference to `_memcmp'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(str.o):str.c:(.text+0x52e): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(str.o):str.c:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `_memset'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(str.o):str.c:(.text+0x589): undefined reference to `_setlocale'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(str.o):str.c:(.text+0x5a2): undefined reference to `__imp__isprint'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(minor_gc.o):minor_gc.c:(.text+0x56d): undefined reference to `_free'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(minor_gc.o):minor_gc.c:(.text+0x6b7): undefined reference to `_realloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `_free'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `_malloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x2f9): undefined reference to `_realloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x5c3): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x7b7): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x89d): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x9f2): undefined reference to `_memcmp'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x1227): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(intern.o):intern.c:(.text+0x13d7): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compare.o):compare.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `_free'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compare.o):compare.c:(.text+0x2a5): undefined reference to `_memcmp'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compare.o):compare.c:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `_strcmp'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compare.o):compare.c:(.text+0x519): undefined reference to `_malloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compare.o):compare.c:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to `_realloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o):floats.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `_atoi'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o):floats.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `_atoi'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o):floats.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o):floats.c:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `_sprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o):floats.c:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `___strtod'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(floats.o):floats.c:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `___strtod'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(weak.o):weak.c:(.text+0x41d): undefined reference to `_memmove'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(major_gc.o):major_gc.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `_realloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(major_gc.o):major_gc.c:(.text+0xb39): undefined reference to `_malloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `_fwrite'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x1bb): undefined reference to `_realloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `__imp___findfirst'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `_malloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x2a2): undefined reference to `_memcpy'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `_strcpy'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x2d1): undefined reference to `__imp___findnext'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `__imp___findclose'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x5ae): undefined reference to `_strcpy'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x616): undefined reference to `_strcpy'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x68c): undefined reference to `_flexdll_dlopen'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x6a3): undefined reference to `_flexdll_dump_exports'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x6b3): undefined reference to `_fflush'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x6c9): undefined reference to `_flexdll_dlclose'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x73b): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x75b): undefined reference to `__imp__SetConsoleCtrlHandler@8'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x7a9): undefined reference to `_malloc'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x863): undefined reference to `_strcpy'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x8bd): undefined reference to `__imp___findfirst'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x93d): undefined reference to `_strcpy'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x961): undefined reference to `__imp___findnext'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x96e): undefined reference to `__imp___findclose'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x98e): undefined reference to `__imp__SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x9aa): undefined reference to `__imp__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime@4'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x9ba): undefined reference to `__imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(win32.o):win32.c:(.text+0x9d0): undefined reference to `__imp__GetCurrentProcessId@0'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(parsing.o):parsing.c:(.text+0x4a2): undefined reference to `_fprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(parsing.o):parsing.c:(.text+0x570): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(parsing.o):parsing.c:(.text+0x57b): undefined reference to `_fprintf'
C:\OCaml\lib/libasmrun.a(compact.o):compact.c:(.text+0x50d): undefined reference to `_memmove'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.31-2/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
```

And I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You can learn about this site at http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior (don't say “this is my first question” or “thanks you in advance”), and if you are going to teach OCaml, you should learn how to write the name from http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/name.en.html

Comment: If you want to do OCaml and not use Windows as suggested by [camlspotter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24928873/1243762), and have only one Windows machine then use a Virtual Machine such as Virtual Box or VMware to run a Linux such as Debian, and then use that to work with OCaml. This is how I do OCaml on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn OCaml, do not use Windows. No matter whether you are a Windows person or not. Period.

With that said, `i686-w64-mingw32-as` is an assembler and it is missing. You must read OCaml's instruction README.win32 carefully and install required softwares.

For the trouble of Cygwin version, I guess you are trying to link your Cygwin object files with MinGW OCaml installation. This wont work at all. Maybe your Cygwin OCaml is totally confused by the env var for MinGW OCaml.

I repeat. OCaml in Windows has so many pit falls for new leaners. Just avoid it.

Comment: On a side note: If you want to learn a language that's very much like OCaml (in fact OCaml is kind of an ancestor to it), but has excellent support in Windows and Linux look at F#.